# Which one is faster, eliminate a small number of duplicate items from a list or just run it directly?

Tags: python

At my current task. The program will generate a unique list for each customer, which would have 5-10 duplicated items in it, the list length is 40.

I need to run this program over millions of customers. So I'm wondering which one is faster?

```
# plan A
customer_list = list(set(customer_list))
for item in customer_list:
    do something
```

---

```
#plan B
for item in customer_list:
    do something
```

Comment: Why not:

#plan a
for item in set(customer_list):
    do something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a set for the completed customers. It should work faster than a list.

```
completed_customer = set()
for item in customer_list:
    if item not in completed_customer:
       -do something //add here the item to the set:
```

Answer (score 0):

You could consider following option as well for the faster performance:

```
completed_customer = []
for item in customer_list:
    if item not in completed_customer:
       -do something
```